# How do I test my Flutter App on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a Flutter app and want to test it on my iPhone. I'm using VS Code and an Android Studio Emulator on Windows. How do I test my Flutter app on my iPhone? Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You will need macOS; either a Mac or a cloud build service

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without MacOS unfortunately. There are some ways to do it though on windows using a virtual box or a service like Appollo, but these are often very slow.

Comment: I have a Mac as well it's just that I'm working on windows. How do I transfer my app to the Mac?

Comment: Use git control on your project and then just pull it down on your mac.